# Insert the mean of each neighbouring value, into the original vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, interpolation

I have a vector, I want to 'pad' it out in MATLAB so that the resultant vector is twice the length, with the extra data being mean values of the original neighboring values.

eg.

`a = [1:10]`

`b` = function of `a`, where `b` is now size 20

`b = 0.5 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5....... 9.5 10`

Answer (score 4):

You could do this in a single line using interpolation (notice that the first digit is NaN because it really isn't defined):

```
interp1(2:2:length(a)*2, a, 1:length(a)*2)
```

The idea is to have evenly spaced `x` values (i.e. 2,4,6...) so that you can have single spaced `xi` values (i.e. 1,2,3,4...) which are thus exactly half way between each `x` value. Then the linear interpolation of the y points will be their means. If you don't like that NaN in the front which I left in mostly to illustrate the point that it's undefined, you can use the `'extrap'` flag in `interp1`, or (better imo) start your `xi` from `2`:

```
interp1(2:2:length(a)*2, a, 1:length(a)*2, 'linear', 'extrap')
```

or

```
interp1(2:2:length(a)*2, a, 2:length(a)*2)
```

Otherwise here is a simple vectorized approach:

```
a = 1:10;
t = [a(1:end-1);a(2:end];
t(2,:) = mean(t);

b = [t(:); a(end)]
```

Comment: brilliant, thank you. I've been staring at the interp1 doc for a while, this has clarified things.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to use [`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) to specify the locations at which you would like to interpolate (and extrapolate) with [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html):

```
>> a = 1:10;
>> b = interp1(a,linspace(0.5,numel(a),2*numel(a)),'linear','extrap')
b =
  Columns 1 through 8
    0.5000    1.0000    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000
  Columns 9 through 16
    4.5000    5.0000    5.5000    6.0000    6.5000    7.0000    7.5000    8.0000
  Columns 17 through 20
    8.5000    9.0000    9.5000   10.0000
```

Using `'linear'` as the method gives the average of the neighboring values, and `'extrap'` says to perform extrapolation (so `b(1)` does not come out as `NaN`, but rather 0.5).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are assuming the "zeroth" entry is zero so that you get the same number of means as the length of the original vector. You can use

```
a2 = filter([0.5,0.5],1,a);
```

to get the vector of means, where the first entry will be the mean of 0 and the first entry in a. Then, you can do whatever you like to interleave the two vectors, e.g,

```
b = zeros(2*max(size(a)),1);
b(1:2:end) = a2;
b(2:2:end) = a;
```

filter is a nifty command, especially for computing discrete convolutions on your original data vector (your neighboring means are a very simple example of a convolution). It also works on matrices either row-by-row or column-by-column.